# NET MAUI iOS, the background color is always gray when the CollectionView is selected

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I am trying to create a UI like the image below.

[image: android]

As you can see, it works fine on Android, but when I run this on iOS, it shows a gray rectangle.

[image: ios]

How can I make this gray rectangle transparent?
Here is the actual code.

```
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single"
                HeightRequest="50"
                WidthRequest="250"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                BackgroundColor="White">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border StrokeThickness="0"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    HeightRequest="50"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 25">
                <Border StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Label Text="{Binding}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="yellow"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>1</x:String>
            <x:String>2</x:String>
            <x:String>3</x:String>
            <x:String>4</x:String>
            <x:String>5</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Yes, it is the case as you said. You can create an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose). Thanks for your support and feedback.